# event.preventdefault() not working in mozilla but working fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Java script:

```
var l=1;
function AddDescription(e){
    alert(123);
    var id = e.id;
    var no = id.split("descript");
    var i=0;
    var max_description = 10;
    event.preventDefault();
    if(i <= max_description) {
          i++;
          $("#adddescription"+no[1]).append("<div id='close"+l+"'  class='form-group'><label for='icode' class='col-md-3 control-label'>Description</label><div class='col-md-5'><input id='description"+no[1]+i+"' class='form-control' name='description"+no[1]+"[]' maxlength='400'><p class='required de"+no[1]+i+"' id='required_description'>Field Required</p></div><a id='hide"+l+"' onclick=closediv(this)><img src='assets/img/close.png'></a></div>");     
          l++;  
    }
}
```

and i am calling this function from :

```
<a href="" id="descript0" class="add-description" onclick="AddDescription(this)" style="float: right;margin-right: 5%">+ Add Point</a>
```

This works fine in chrome but in mozilla it reloads the page.It has something related to event.preventdefault .Please help what wrong i am doing?

Comment: Can you explain what makes you think it has something to do with `preventDefault`?

Answer (score 2):

Because `event` is undefined and `e` is a bad variable name since people will think it means event, not element.

```
onclick="AddDescription(event, this)"
```

and

```
function AddDescription(event, elem){
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log(elem.id);
}
```